# Psycopg2 Insert into with conditions

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this table in Postgres

```
 ID|     | IP             | Remote-as  | IRR-Record |   
 1 |     | 192.168.1.1    |100         |            |        
 2 |     | 192.168.2.1    |200         |            |       
 3 |     | 192.168.3.1    |300         |            |        
 4 |     | 192.168.4.1    |400         |            |
```

I want to add for each ip address the IIR-Record.
The IIR-record is inside a variable.

```
c = conn.cursor()
query = 'select * From "peers"'
c.execute(query)

 for row in c:
       c.execute('''INSERT INTO "peers" ("IRR- 
   Record") VALUES(variable)
       conn.commit()
```

This code doesn't work because i gat the IIR-Record at the end of my table.

```
 ID|     | IP             | Remote-as  | IRR-Record |   
 1 |     | 192.168.1.1    |100         |            |        
 2 |     | 192.168.2.1    |200         |            |       
 3 |     | 192.168.3.1    |300         |            |        
 4 |     | 192.168.4.1    |400         | 
                                       |Variable
                                       |Variable
                                       |Varibale
```

any Idea!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an UPDATE query instead of INSERT

```
UPDATE peers
SET IRR-Record = <<MYVALUE>>
WHERE ID = <<MYID>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something like this:

```
for row in c:
    c.execute('UPDATE peers SET "IRR-Record"=%s WHERE ID=%s', (record_var, id_var))
```

Edit: Use UPDATE sql statement as per @Devasta's answer.